# SwiftUI: Type 'Timer' has no member 'publish'

Tags: xcode, timer, swiftui, publish

does anybody know why my Timer has no member called 'publish'?

```
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
```

XCode tells me:

- Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'common'
- Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'main'
- **Type 'Timer' has no member 'publish'**

Thanks for your help!!

```
    import SwiftUI

let defaultTimeRemaining: CGFloat = 10
let lineWidth: CGFloat = 30
let radius: CGFloat = 70

struct Timer: View {
    
    @State private var isActive = false
    @State private var timeRemaining: CGFloat = defaultTimeRemaining
    @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct Timer_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Timer()
    }
}
```

Comment: Where have you written?

Comment: in content view

Answer (score 3):

this is the way I implement a timer.

```
@State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
```

Do you have imported SwiftUI?

Did you also implement the timer before the body part?

I don't know why but maybe you need @State before the variable declaration. I also think a Timer can not be a `let`. I think you have to use `var`-

Edit:
I think I know what the problem is. You named the `struct` "Timer". When you want so create the `Timer` Swift try to call `.publish` on the `View Timer` rather than the `Timer` you actually want. Rename the `View` to TimerView(or something else) and try again.

Comment: I updated the questions cause this doesnt work at all :(

Comment: @János Dreveton I edited my answer

Comment: Thank you man!! Never though of smth stupid!! :)

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help